# Transfering data from popup alert (User input) to database

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite, ipad

how do i transfer the data from pop up alert which require user input to database? the user input from the pop up is already stored in a variable and how do i create an sqlite database and move the value of the variable ( user input) to the database. Much help appreciated thanks :) i'am creating an application for ipad use=ing xcode 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use sqlite database then,
The thing you have to do is to learn how to use sqlite database with ios apps.

Create sqlite database file & Create Tables in database

Add this file to your app

Access this file using your code

perform operation on the database file using your code

Here i am posting some useful links that will guide you thorough out the process.

[Link 1](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

[Link 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app)